# Synchronize two remote git repositories automatically

Tags: git, shell, githooks, synchronize

As an interim solution, I would like to synchronize two remote git repositories automatically. Just to have the possibility to migrate step by step. Both repositories will be used for push and fetch. Is it possible to have both repos always in the same state? I thought about server-side hooks on both repositories which will push changes immediately to the other server. Any hints how to realise that?

Answer (score 0):

True read/write multi-master operation is not possible with git. If one client pushes commit to branch on first server, and another client pushes different commit to the same branch on second server, then who gets to decide which commit wins?

You might say that then it should merge, but what if one commit has just one line `x=1`, and another `x=2`? This decision can be only made by human.

If you can accept having only one repository to be read/write and others read/only, then it is very easy to do.

Comment: Maybe it would be possible to lock the branch on both servers before push? 1) Push to first server, 2) lock branch on both server, 3) if  successful allow push to first server, 4) sync with second server, 5) release everything. Otherwise reject push to first server. Not sure if something like that is possible in git.

Comment: All git operations except for push and fetch are always local, this is what makes it fast. Your solution would require always asking second partner in mirror on whether it is ok to proceed with almost any operation. This will make git depend on network latency, and what's worse, on second server being always online. What if network connectivity between servers is temporarily lost? Should both deny any operation?

Comment: So the idea was still to make changes locally (without any asking / synchronization etc.). There still would be just two exceptions push and fetch were the second partner has to be asked. Broken network connectivity should be an exceptions and in that case somebody has to fix this manually. As I said this just should be a temporary solution.